# Project import error when using Eclipse 

Tags: maven, maven-2, eclipse-plugin, m2e

I am getting the following error when trying to import some existing project (couple of years old project).

"No marketplace entries found to handle maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."

I have tried to read information on this error.. but can't find anything that tell what's wrong, and how to fix it.

Help? I have Eclipse Indigo, and M2E Eclipse Plugin

Update - Looks like this is related to Eclipse Indigo having Maven 3, and my pom xml files being old (maven2). I am reverting back to Eclipse Ganymede... :(

Comment: Note:  I doubt updating POM.xml is a permanent option.. because its not my project.

Comment: Is this really a Maven 2/3 project or may be a Maven-1 project?

Comment: @khmarbaise what are the implications? and how do I find it out?

Answer (score 0):

This probably relates to a M2E connector not existing for the "run" goal of the maven-antrun-plugin. See http://objectledge.org/confluence/display/TOOLS/M2E+Connectors for more information.

Eclipse is only able to perform a subset of Maven build functions, and the M2E Eclipse plugin helps expand Eclipse's repertoire using its "Connectors", which are available for download in the Marketplace.

Comment: link not accessible. Can you provide new link ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy sorry, been a long time since I looked at this stuff - try googling "M2E Eclipse Antrun."  These days I use IntelliJ and SBT.